# Storing a future in a list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, future

I want to store the futures of several threads spawned using async in a list to retrieve their results later.

```
future<int> f = async(doLater, parameter);
list<future<int>> l;
l.push_back(f);
```

However the compiler prints the following error message

> /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:115:71: error: use of deleted function 'std::future<_Res>::future(const std::future<_Res>&) [with _Res = int; std::future<_Res> = std::future]'

Am i doing something wrong or aren't lists supposed to store futures? If they are not, what to use instead?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdcTmpvDO0I

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't understand how the video is relevant :S

Comment: You just have to move it :)

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any way to do a move in a style that is more in a way like what i postet rather than pasting all the code in a single line? (The original code is already long enough...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`std::future` is not copyable - you need to move into the list. Either:

```
future<int> f = async(doLater, parameter);
list<future<int>> l;
l.push_back(std::move(f));
```

or:

```
list<future<int>> l;
l.push_back(async(doLater, parameter));
```

will work, with the latter being preferable since it doesn't leave a moved-from object littering the scope.