# c++ std::future is not getting called

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I am working with `std::async` and `std::future` in c++, but am having a bit of trouble.
When I run this code, i expect to see (in the stdout) `"hello world"` but, instead I get nothing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  future<string>* test;
};

string getStr() {
  return "hello world";
}

A callA() {

  future<string> a = async(&getStr);

  return A{ &a };
}

int main() {
  A a = callA();
  cout << a.test->get() << endl;
}
```

I am using a pointer to a future because in my real program, i have another struct in place of the `std::string`:

```
struct A;
struct B;

typedef struct A {
  future<B>* b;
} A;

typedef struct B {
  A a;
} B;
```

and even if i don't use a pointer it will give me this error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::future<_Res>::future(const std::future<_Res>&) [with _Res = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
```

(For the above error, i know that i can use std::move to fix it as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126551/storing-a-future-in-a-list), but i need to use the pointer)

So how can i actually get the output of `"hello world"` from this program?

Comment: This might have been caught by the compiler if you turn on warnings, btw.

Comment: I am using mingw-w64, and no warning was given for this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future is destroyed as soon as `callA()` returns, so you have a pointer to an object that no longer exists.  `a.test->get()` is therefore undefined behavior, and anything might happen -- including indefinitely blocking, or crashing, or actually printing the right result.

If you wish to return it from the function as a pointer, then use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  unique_ptr<future<string>> test;
};

string getStr() {
  return "hello world";
}

A callA() {
  future<string> a = async(&getStr);

  return A{ make_unique<future<string>>(std::move(a)) };
}

int main() {
  A a = callA();
  cout << a.test->get() << endl;
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfd4bc5c85dbbff1))

Side note: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250). Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

you use a pointer to a temporary object. the temporary object is destroyed at the exit of the function. so you can move your future object to your struct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  future<string> test;
};

string getStr() {
  return "hello world";
}

A callA() {

  future<string> a = async(&getStr);

  return A{ std::move(a) };
}

int main() {
  A a = callA();
  cout << a.test.get() << endl;
}
```

if for some reason you have to use a pointer - then you should prolong the lifetime of your future. (e.g. add the future to a container and later remove from it after the usage of the future)

Comment: yes, i know i can do this, but i need to keep it as a pointer

Comment: @Ankizle is smart pointer good enough ?

Comment: I used the `unique pointer` given by cdhowie, and that worked. Thanks for the help though!